# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForArmRelease'

Tags: android, android-studio, testing, automated-tests

Build is not generating

I am using Espresso for automated testing but build is not generating.
and I found that this error are generated when this below mentioned dependency is included.
    compile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2'

Not sure, is it the only reason for error.

here is the stack trace

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleArmRelease]
Warning:org.hamcrest.integration.EasyMock2Adapter: can't find superclass or interface org.easymock.IArgumentMatcher
Warning:org.hamcrest.integration.JMock1Adapter: can't find superclass or interface org.jmock.core.Constraint
Warning:library class android.test.AndroidTestCase extends or implements program class junit.framework.TestCase
Warning:library class android.test.AndroidTestRunner extends or implements program class junit.runner.BaseTestRunner
Warning:library class android.test.InstrumentationTestCase extends or implements program class junit.framework.TestCase
Warning:library class android.test.InstrumentationTestSuite extends or implements program class junit.framework.TestSuite
Warning:library class android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder$FailedToCreateTests extends or implements program class junit.framework.TestCase
Warning:com.squareup.javawriter.JavaWriter: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Modifier
Warning:org.hamcrest.JMock1Matchers: can't find referenced class org.jmock.core.Constraint
Warning:org.hamcrest.beans.HasPropertyWithValue: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning:org.hamcrest.beans.HasPropertyWithValue$2: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning:org.hamcrest.beans.PropertyUtil: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning:org.hamcrest.beans.PropertyUtil: can't find referenced class java.beans.Introspector
Warning:org.hamcrest.beans.PropertyUtil: can't find referenced class java.beans.BeanInfo
Warning:org.hamcrest.beans.PropertyUtil: can't find referenced class java.beans.IntrospectionException
Warning:org.hamcrest.beans.PropertyUtil: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning:org.hamcrest.beans.PropertyUtil: can't find referenced class java.beans.Introspector
Warning:org.hamcrest.beans.PropertyUtil: can't find referenced class java.beans.BeanInfo
Warning:org.hamcrest.beans.PropertyUtil: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning:org.hamcrest.beans.PropertyUtil: can't find referenced class java.beans.IntrospectionException
Warning:org.hamcrest.beans.PropertyUtil: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning:org.hamcrest.beans.SamePropertyValuesAs: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning:org.hamcrest.beans.SamePropertyValuesAs$PropertyMatcher: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning:org.hamcrest.integration.EasyMock2Adapter: can't find referenced class org.easymock.EasyMock
Warning:org.hamcrest.integration.EasyMock2Adapter: can't find referenced class org.easymock.IArgumentMatcher
Warning:org.hamcrest.integration.EasyMock2Adapter: can't find referenced class org.easymock.EasyMock
Warning:org.hamcrest.integration.EasyMock2Adapter: can't find referenced class org.easymock.IArgumentMatcher
Warning:org.hamcrest.integration.JMock1Adapter: can't find referenced class org.jmock.core.Constraint
Warning:org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ManagementFactory
Warning:org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ThreadMXBean
Warning:org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ManagementFactory
Warning:org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ThreadMXBean
Warning:org.junit.rules.DisableOnDebug: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ManagementFactory
Warning:org.junit.rules.DisableOnDebug: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.RuntimeMXBean
Warning:org.junit.rules.DisableOnDebug: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ManagementFactory
Warning:org.junit.rules.DisableOnDebug: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.RuntimeMXBean
Warning:there were 91 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
Warning:there were 5 instances of library classes depending on program classes.
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Error:Execution failed for task  ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForArmRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Information:BUILD FAILED
```